# Objective-C Runtime - Run Code at Deallocation of Any Object

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I was reading this article by Jeff Kelley and trying to do the same. However the code was written before ARC was adopted and now fails to compile.

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/04/11/fun-with-the-objective-c-runtime-run-code-at-deallocation-of-any-object/

The main problem is in this part of the printout, some casting errors and then blocked release messages. I found it to be a very interesting example but I can't seem to get it to work.

The problems are:

**0.** Autosynthesized property 'block' will use synthesized instance variable '_block', not existing instance variable 'block' **on the** @implementation JKBlockExecutor

**1.** Cast of block pointer type 'voidBlock' (aka 'void (^)(void)') to C pointer type 'const void *' requires a bridged cast **and** Cast of C pointer type 'void *' to block pointer type 'typeof (aBlock)' (aka 'void (^__strong)(void)') requires a bridged cast" **on the** block = Block_copy(aBlock); **line**

**2.** Cast of block pointer type 'voidBlock' (aka 'void (^)(void)') to C pointer type 'const void *' requires a bridged cast **on** Block_release(block);

```
typedef void (^voidBlock)(void);

@interface JKBlockExecutor : NSObject {
    voidBlock   block;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) voidBlock    block;

- (id)initWithBlock:(voidBlock)block;

@end

@implementation JKBlockExecutor

@synthesize block;

- (id)initWithBlock:(voidBlock)aBlock
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        block = Block_copy(aBlock);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (block != nil) {
        block();
        Block_release(block);
    }

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This is where he creates a category on NSObject.

```
const void *runAtDeallocBlockKey = &runAtDeallocBlockKey;

@interface NSObject (JK_RunAtDealloc)

- (void)runAtDealloc:(voidBlock)block;

@end

@implementation NSObject (JK_RunAtDealloc)

- (void)runAtDealloc:(voidBlock)block
{
    if (block) {
        JKBlockExecutor *executor = [[JKBlockExecutor alloc] initWithBlock:block];

        objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                                 runAtDeallocBlockKey,
                                 executor,
                                 OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

        [executor release];
    }
}

@end
```

This is how you execute the example.

```
NSObject *foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];

[foo runAtDealloc:^{
    NSLog(@"Deallocating foo!");
}];

[foo release];
```

Or another way to get other information.

```
NSObject *foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];

__block id objectRef = foo;

[foo runAtDealloc:^{
    NSLog(@"Deallocating foo at address %p!", objectRef);
}];

[foo release];
```

Can this code be fixed somehow? I took out all the release messages to no avail.

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: What output from debugging have you gotten? SDK used? Deployment Target?

Comment: Edited the question too... for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below builds and works (or at least seems so), and prints "Deallocating foo!" when I expect it to print it. Part 1:

```
typedef void (^voidBlock)(void);

@interface JKBlockExecutor : NSObject {
    voidBlock   block;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) voidBlock    block;

- (id)initWithBlock:(voidBlock)block;

@end

@implementation JKBlockExecutor

@synthesize block = block;

- (id)initWithBlock:(voidBlock)aBlock
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        block = [aBlock copy];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (block != nil) {
        block();
        block = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Part 2:

```
const void *runAtDeallocBlockKey = &runAtDeallocBlockKey;

@interface NSObject (JK_RunAtDealloc)

- (void)runAtDealloc:(voidBlock)block;

@end

@implementation NSObject (JK_RunAtDealloc)

- (void)runAtDealloc:(voidBlock)block
{
    if (block) {
        JKBlockExecutor *executor = [[JKBlockExecutor alloc] initWithBlock:block];

        objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                                 runAtDeallocBlockKey,
                                 executor,
                                 OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
}

@end
```

Testing if it works:

```
@autoreleasepool {
        NSObject *foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];

        [foo runAtDealloc:^{
            NSLog(@"Deallocating foo!");
        }];
    }
```

**EDIT**

Changed `Block_release(block);` to `block = nil;`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to fix it. It does indeed work! Still getting a Cast of block pointer type 'voidBlock' (aka 'void (^)(void)') to C pointer type 'const void *' requires a bridged cast in Part 1 at  Block_release(block); but if you comment it out. Is that line needed? What does it do?

Comment: Commenting that out might lead to memory leak (I'm not sure if properties are automatically `nil`'ed on deallocation). What you can do is to replace `Block_release(block);` with `block = nil;`. That should do it :)

Comment: Perfect. Edit the answer with block = nil and I will accept it.

Comment: Deal. For the record, I wasn't getting this last warning (on `Block_release()`). The rest were consistent with your question though.

Comment: I'm on 5.1 too. Thing is, that warning should be there, so not sure what's wrong with my project.

Comment: The copy in `block = [aBlock copy];` is unnecessary. Assigning to a strong variable of block type in ARC automatically copies.

Comment: @Andrey: `block = nil;` is unnecessary. There is basically no point to setting an instance variable to `nil` in `dealloc`, in either MRC or ARC. In MRC, the block would be leaked. In ARC, all instance variables are released when the object is deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more about the code below ,please go to [***Fun With the Objective-C Runtime: Run Code at Deallocation of Any Object***](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/04/11/fun-with-the-objective-c-runtime-run-code-at-deallocation-of-any-object/)

Part 1：create one class: the object We Want To Be Released When That Happens--- this class is like an event：when the target obj dealloc,it happens。use block to execute the event 。

```
// .m file
// http://weibo.com/luohanchenyilong/
// https://github.com/ChenYilong
// the object We Want To Be Released When That Happens--- this class is like an event：when the target obj dealloc,it happens。use block to execute the event 。


typedef void (^voidBlock)(void);

@interface CYLBlockExecutor : NSObject 

- (id)initWithBlock:(voidBlock)block;

@end


// .m file
// http://weibo.com/luohanchenyilong/
// https://github.com/ChenYilong
// the object We Want To Be Released When That Happens--- this class is like an event：when the target obj dealloc,it happens。use block to execute the event 。

#import "CYLBlockExecutor.h"

@interface CYLBlockExecutor() {
    voidBlock _block;
}
@implementation CYLBlockExecutor

- (id)initWithBlock:(voidBlock)aBlock
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _block = [aBlock copy];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    _block ? _block() : nil;
}

@end
```

Part 2：core code：use runtime to realize cyl_runAtDealloc method

```
// CYLNSObject+RunAtDealloc.h file
// http://weibo.com/luohanchenyilong/
// https://github.com/ChenYilong
// use runtime to realize cyl_runAtDealloc method

#import "CYLBlockExecutor.h"

const void *runAtDeallocBlockKey = &runAtDeallocBlockKey;

@interface NSObject (CYLRunAtDealloc)

- (void)cyl_runAtDealloc:(voidBlock)block;

@end


// CYLNSObject+RunAtDealloc.m file
// http://weibo.com/luohanchenyilong/
// https://github.com/ChenYilong
// use runtime to realize cyl_runAtDealloc method

#import "CYLNSObject+RunAtDealloc.h"
#import "CYLBlockExecutor.h"

@implementation NSObject (CYLRunAtDealloc)

- (void)cyl_runAtDealloc:(voidBlock)block
{
    if (block) {
        CYLBlockExecutor *executor = [[CYLBlockExecutor alloc] initWithBlock:block];

        objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                                 runAtDeallocBlockKey,
                                 executor,
                                 OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
}

@end
```

How to use :

```
#import "CYLNSObject+RunAtDealloc.h"
```

then

```
    NSObject *foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    [foo cyl_runAtDealloc:^{
        NSLog(@"Deallocating foo!");
    }];
```